# Does Enumerable.Range(1,10000000) consume a large amount of memory?

Tags: c#, linq

I do know that Enumerable.Range(..).ToArray() will consume memory as big as the size of the range, but I want to confirm that Enumerable.Range(..) without any ToArray or ToList conversion is similar to a for index loop

For example:

I am using below code to check if an integer array items are in **exact** sequential order:

```
int[] numSequence = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
//Check if they are in sequence or not
bool isInSequence = numSequence.SequenceEqual(Enumerable.Range(1, numSequence.Count()));
```

Although I am not converting `Enumerable.Range` to an array, My concern is the memory consumption use of it. Does it consume large amount of memory when I have a very large array?

My guess is that it properly uses C# `yield` and it is equivalent with using a for loop. But I wanted to confirm here.

Comment: In many cases, Range objects are just made up of 3 numbers: the start, end, and step. I suspect that's probably the case here. Also, running this through a profiler would easily answer the question.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,fda9d378095a6464

Comment: `Does it consume large amount of memory when I have a very large array?` No.

Comment: @mjwills Technically speaking the question is wrong from the start: there is no array.

Comment: There is - the first line @PatrickHofman .

Comment: Not in the call to `Enumerable.Range` @mjwills

Comment: You have to read that statement in context. Read the whole post again. His reference to `array` is related to the first line of the code.

Comment: So when you ran the code that you've written and measured the memory what actually happened?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036033/how-does-a-streaming-operator-differ-from-deferred-execution

Comment: You appear to be concerned with aspects of performance. It might be worth comparing the LINQ version against checking that a(i) - a(i-1) = 1 for 1 < i < a.Length, just in case the procedural method is an improvement (by an appropriate metric) over the declarative version. And then there is [The Fallacy of Premature Optimization](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the CPU penalty of excess and unnecessary memory consumption should not be underestimated. Memory management operations such as garbage collection can cost more than optimizations such as a(i) - a(i-1) = 1 for 1 < i < a.Length,

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no memory allocated inside that method [besides one or two small integers](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,fda9d378095a6464), no matter how many iterations you make. All the looping uses CPU power, but no memory at all.

As you can see from the code, nothing is materialized into an array the `Enumerable.Range`. As notes in comments, `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` enumerates the second sequence, so no problem there either.

Comment: Plus one for the reference to the .NET framework source code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Lots of LINQ queries materialize entire collections.  Some materialize none, some all, some materialize some but not all, it all depends on the specific method.  The point that the materialization happens is also not consistent.  For some it's right away, others on request of the first item, etc.

Comment: You are right. I updated my answer to reflect that @Servy